# Setting Hardware Breakpoints

Tags: assembly

I'd like to understand how HBP's works,

Can you tell me how to set hardware breakpoints using assembly?

Comment: -1 start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint#Hardware, come back when you have concrete questions.

Comment: i just want to know how to set a hardware breakpoint using assembly, messing directly with DR x86 registers, i'm sorry if you did not understand my question properly

Answer (score 3):

Which kind of hardware breakpoint do you mean?  There are the type set with [80x86 debug registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register).  There are micro controllers with a [JTAG interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG#Communications_model) which allow full speed execution and hardware breakpoints.  And there is the breakpoint possible with dedicated external hardware, most often an [In-Circuit Emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-circuit_emulator) or ICE.

Each has a specific mechanism for setting up a breakpoint.  The links I provided should get you started.